# C# using ebay LMS Api getting exception

Tags: c#, file-transfer, nopcommerce, ebay-api

Ok so I'm trying to send a zipped file to ebay LMS api, but this stuff is very poorly documented for a newbie like me.

This is the exception I get:

```
    System.InvalidOperationException: Could not find endpoint element with name 'FileTransferServiceSOAP' and contract 'FileTransferServicePort' in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be because no configuration file was found for your application, or because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the client element.
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.ConfigLoader.LoadChannelBehaviors(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName, Configuration configuration)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.ApplyConfiguration(String configurationName)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.InitializeEndpoint(String configurationName, EndpointAddress address)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
   at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateSimplexFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ConfigurationEndpointTrait`1.CreateChannelFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.CreateChannelFactoryRef(EndpointTrait`1 endpointTrait)
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1.InitializeChannelFactoryRef()
   at System.ServiceModel.ClientBase`1..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName)
   at FileTransferServicePortClient..ctor(String endpointConfigurationName)
   at Nop.Plugin.Widgets.DbgEnhancements.Services.EbayWebService.UploadFile(String jobID, String fileRefId, String fileName, String SecurityToken)
   at Nop.Plugin.Widgets.DbgEnhancements.Services.EbayWebService.SendEbayBulkLMSRequest(String filePathZip)
```

This is the code for my ebaywebservice:

```
public virtual void SendEbayBulkLMSRequest(string filePathZip)
    {
        var ebayAuthTokenSetting = _settingService.GetSettingByKey(
                            "ebaysetting.authtoken", "");

        try
        {
            //Get the parameters from the app.config file
            string jobID = "123";
            string fileRefID = "123";
            string fileName = filePathZip;
            string SecurityToken = ebayAuthTokenSetting;

            // Upload file
            UploadFileResponse uploadResponse = UploadFile(jobID, fileRefID, fileName, SecurityToken);

            // display response details
            displayResponse(uploadResponse, fileName);
            Debug.WriteLine("uploadResponse");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("\n An exception occured: \n\n" + e + "\n");
        }
    }
```

It says something about app setting, but I don't see why I can't store settings in the back end of nopcommerce.

Here are the other methods I'm using for file uploading:

```
//Call uploadFile
    public static UploadFileResponse UploadFile(string jobID, string fileRefId, string fileName, string SecurityToken)
    {
        FileTransferServicePortClient client = new FileTransferServicePortClient("FileTransferServiceSOAP");
        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
        {

            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequest);

            //Set HTTP headers
            setHeaders(httpRequest, SecurityToken);

            //Create upload file request
            UploadFileRequest uploadReq = new UploadFileRequest();

            uploadReq.fileAttachment = getFileAttachment(fileName);
            uploadReq.fileReferenceId = fileRefId;
            uploadReq.taskReferenceId = jobID;
            uploadReq.fileFormat = "gzip";

            //Make the uploadFile call and return the response
            UploadFileResponse uploadResponse = client.uploadFile(uploadReq);

            return uploadResponse;

        }
    }

    //Sets HTTP headers for the request
    public static HttpRequestMessageProperty setHeaders(HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest, string SecurityToken)
    {

        //Add the request headers
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-TOKEN", SecurityToken);
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME", "FileTransferService");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION", "1.0.0");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT", "XML");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT", "XML");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL", "SOAP12");
        httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "uploadFile");

        return httpRequest;
    }

    //Reads the file from the location specified
    public static FileAttachment getFileAttachment(String fileName)
    {
        FileAttachment attachment = new FileAttachment();

        FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(fileName);
        byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
        fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);

        attachment.Data = data;
        attachment.SizeSpecified = true;
        attachment.Size = fs.Length;

        return attachment;

    }

    //Displays the result of the uploadFile call
    public static void displayResponse(UploadFileResponse uploadResponse, string fileName)
    {

        string txt = "";

        switch (uploadResponse.ack)
        {
            case AckValue.Success:
                Debug.WriteLine("uploadFile Status: Success");
                Debug.WriteLine(uploadResponse.timestamp);
                txt += fileName + " was successfully uploaded to the server.\n\n";
                Debug.WriteLine(txt);
                break;

            case AckValue.Failure:
                Debug.WriteLine(uploadResponse.timestamp);
                Debug.WriteLine("uploadFile Status: Failure");
                break;

            case AckValue.Warning:
                Debug.WriteLine(uploadResponse.timestamp);
                Debug.WriteLine("uploadFile Status: Warning");
                break;
            case AckValue.PartialFailure:
                Debug.WriteLine(uploadResponse.timestamp);
                Debug.WriteLine("uploadFile Status: PartialFailure");
                break;

        }

        // display error messages received if any
        if (uploadResponse.errorMessage != null)
        {
            foreach (ErrorData error in uploadResponse.errorMessage)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(error.message);
            }
        }

    }
```

I'm working [from this page](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1336) and if you go down to the file attachments there is the FTSSample.zip which I'm using in nopcommerce as a service.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong, cheers.

Comment: 1. why is this related to nopCommerce? what you are trying to achieve? 2. that error is because of endpoint, you have to add endpoints for web services.

Comment: @Div thanks, I got past this exception but now I got another problem here > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48372246/c-sharp-configuring-web-socket-bindings-for-ebay-uploads-to-lms