# C# Configuring web socket bindings for ebay uploads to LMS

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, wcf

Ok so I'm trying to get this working but can't seem to get it right.
I need to create a web socket http binding for ebay LMS.

This is my web config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BulkDataExchangeService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
       openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
       sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
       transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
       maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
       messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8"
       useDefaultWebProxy="true" allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192"
          maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096"
          maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
          enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"
            proxyCredentialType="None" realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows"
            negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default"
            establishSecurityContext="true" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="https://webservices.sandbox.ebay.com/BulkDataExchangeService"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BulkDataExchangeService"
    contract="BulkDataExchangeServicePort" name="BulkDataExchangeService">
    <identity>
      <userPrincipalName value="machine\user" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is my code to create the upload request:

```
private void CreateUploadJobEbay()
    {
        var ebayAuthTokenSetting = _settingService.GetSettingByKey(
                            "ebaysetting.authtoken", "");

        //EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://webservices.sandbox.ebay.com/BulkDataExchangeService");

        BulkDataExchangeServicePortClient client = new BulkDataExchangeServicePortClient("BulkDataExchangeService");

        using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
        {
            HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();

            OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, httpRequest);

            //Add the request headers
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SECURITY-TOKEN", ebayAuthTokenSetting);
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME", "BulkDataExchangeService");
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION", "1.0.0");
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL", "SOAP12");
            httpRequest.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "createUploadJob");

            //Create the request
            CreateUploadJobRequest req = new CreateUploadJobRequest();

            //Supply additional parameters

            //The UUID must be unique. Once used, you can't use it again

            req.UUID = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

            //Specify job type

            req.uploadJobType = "AddFixedPriceItem";

            req.fileType = FileType.XML;

            //Get the response

            CreateUploadJobResponse resp = client.createUploadJob(req);

            Debug.WriteLine("resp = " + resp);
        }
    }
```

The BulkDataExchangeService comes from [this link](https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1335) Down near the bottom you will see BDXSmaple.zip which contains the code.

The problem I'm having is with the service contract `contract="BulkDataExchangeServicePort"`

> If I hover over the contract it gives me the error "The contract
>   attribute is invalid - The value BulkDataExchangeServicePort is
>   invalid according to it's data type clientContractType - The
>   enumeration constraint failed"

In the debug window I get this message:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in
>   System.ServiceModel.dll Could not find endpoint element with name
>   'BulkDataExchangeService' and contract 'BulkDataExchangeServicePort'
>   in the ServiceModel client configuration section. This might be
>   because no configuration file was found for your application, or
>   because no endpoint element matching this name could be found in the
>   client element.

I'm really not sure where I'm goign wrong with the service contract. can anyone help. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I now know what was going on, I'm working with nopCommerce atm as a solution in visual studio.

What I was doing was adding the endpoint to the wrong config file.

Once it was moved from nop.Admin web.config to nop.Web web.config it worked.
Hope this might help someone else :)